# Removing extra line space in Text box in Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When I press "return" in a text box I get an unwanted blank line between the lines of text.  How can I get rid of it?

Comment: How can this be recreated, it doesn't happen for me.

Comment: I found the answer myself - by editing in HTML and replacing <p></p> paragraph breaks with an ordinary <br> break the blank space disappears.  I don't know if the paragraph "style" can be edited to avoid this happening but I only had a few changes to make so it wasn't too bad.

Answer (score 5):

Click the text box (not into it), go to the Text tab, and uncheck Formatted Text. This will get rid of that unwanted space.

Comment: this actually worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me, editing the HTML worked as follows:
changing the value of *line-height* from *22.4 px* to *1.2*

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives me a new line without any space between lines. I'm using Chrome on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It must be some kind of problem with underlying text engine (HTML/CSS/JS), but as **user2159614** mentioned before: you can use either <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and one should work as desired. For me second one goes to the next line with no extra space between lines as first does. Also I've noticed it may differ from one shape to another as I had this problem in one shape (heading) but not in others (Enter worked as expected with no extra line).
This is weird but at least now I can manipulate it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but an easy improvement: Highlight the newline and change the font to something very small.